# Angular multiple ngIf multiple condition assign as value?

Tags: angular

how do you assign a as value when there is multiple condition using `*ngIf`

e.g can i pass either orange or apple as "as value"

```
<div *ngIf="orange && apple as apple">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="orange && apple">
  ...
</div>
```

Will show the div if both apple and orange are truthy.

```
<div *ngIf="(orange && apple) as appleAndOrange">
  ...
</div>
```

Will show the div if both apple and orange are truthy and define a view variable called appleAndOrange available to the children of the div but it will always contain the value of apple as it is second in and and statement.

Comment: Depends on the value or apple and orange, two strings 'first' && 'second' will be 'second'

Comment: Can u setup a simple stackbliz to demo the result? I will then accept it as an answer

Comment: Try changing the values for apple and orange and you will see that it wont show if either are falsey and will always be apple if they are both truthy.